I keep running into "Oauth Google Access blocked: This app’s request is invalid" with my python program is using Flask
This is one of many attempts to try and learn how to make a local program with Flask and run it from Google Cloud Shell.  I have laid all the problem in the comments at the top of the program.  I also have a html template include after the demonstration program.
# copied from https://github.com/piyush-singhal/oauth-python/blob/main/app.py
# this seems the simplest way to authenicate with Google 
# developed on local box and works well.  It pops a browser window open and lets me pick my Google account on my browser
# 
# deploy to Google Shell in the GCP
# I get the expected screen
#   Example of Google Login in Python Flask Application
#   You are not logged in, Click on the below link to sign in with google.
# I click the link and then i get the dreaded 
#   "Access blocked: This app’s request is invalid"
# Any help you can offer would be appreciated.
#
# here is my debug log (with my client-id channged to protect me)
# start the logging.debug
# Hello  line 74
# Hello  line 76
 # * Debugger is active!
 # * Debugger PIN: 127-742-122
# Hello  line 78
# Hello  line 80
# Hello  line 81  Google.base_url    == https://www.googleapis.com/
# Hello  line 82  user_info_endpoint == /oauth2/v2/userinfo
# 127.0.0.1 - - [15/Jul/2024 11:41:41] "GET /?authuser=0 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
# Hello  line 89
# Hello  line 91 my_url_for-->/login/google
# 127.0.0.1 - - [15/Jul/2024 11:42:30] "GET /login HTTP/1.1" 302 -
# client_id = 0000000000000-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com
# Generated new state V18oHjswxgqJML9VgmF7ujpaiLi6KD.
# state = V18oHjswxgqJML9VgmF7ujpaiLi6KD
# redirect URL = https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?response_type=code&client_id=0000000000000-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%3A5000%2Flogin%2Fgoogle%2Fauthorized&scope=profile+email&state=V18oHjswxgqJML9VgmF7ujpaiLi6KD&prompt=consent


import os
import sys
from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect, url_for
from flask_dance.contrib.google import make_google_blueprint, google
import logging
import json
import json as json_module

app = Flask(__name__)

# Configuration
with open('./credentials.json', 'r') as file:
    json = json.load(file)
client_id     = json['installed']['client_id']
client_secret = json['installed']['client_secret']
secret_key    = os.environ.get("SECRET_KEY") or os.urandom(24)

logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stdout, level=logging.DEBUG, format='%(message)s')

print("start the logging.debug")
logging.debug("Hello  line 52")

app.config['DEBUG'] = True
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = secret_key

logging.debug("Hello  line 57")

os.environ['OAUTHLIB_INSECURE_TRANSPORT'] = '1'
os.environ['OAUTHLIB_RELAX_TOKEN_SCOPE'] = '1'

blueprint = make_google_blueprint(
    client_id=client_id,
    client_secret=client_secret,
    reprompt_consent=True,
    scope=["profile", "email"]
)
app.register_blueprint(blueprint, url_prefix="/login")

@app.route("/")
def index():
    google_data = None
    user_info_endpoint = '/oauth2/v2/userinfo'
    logging.debug("Hello  line 74")
    if google.authorized:
        logging.debug("Hello  line 76")
        google_data = google.get(user_info_endpoint).json()
        logging.debug("Hello  line 78")

    logging.debug("Hello  line 80")
    logging.debug("Hello  line 81  Google.base_url    == " + google.base_url)
    logging.debug("Hello  line 82  user_info_endpoint == " + user_info_endpoint)
    return render_template('index.j2',
                           google_data=google_data,
                           fetch_url=google.base_url + user_info_endpoint)

@app.route('/login')
def login():
    logging.debug("Hello  line 89")
    my_url_for=url_for('google.login')
    logging.debug("Hello  line 91 my_url_for-->" + my_url_for )
    return redirect(my_url_for)
    #return redirect('/login/google')  #this works

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()

here is index.j2 in the template folder
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="">

<head>
  <title>Google Oauth 2.0 Login for python Flask application</title>
  <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
</head>

<body>
  <h3>Example of Google Login in Python Flask Application</h3>
  {% if not google_data %}
    <p style="color:#333;">You are not logged in, Click on the below link to sign in with google.</p>
    <a href="/login" class="google-btn">
      <div class="google-icon-wrapper">
        <img class="google-icon" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c1/Google_%22G%22_logo.svg"/>
      </div>
      <p class="btn-text"><b>Sign in with google</b></p>
    </a>
  {% else %}
    <p>Hi {{ google_data.name }}, [<strong>{{ google_data.email }}</strong>]. You have logged in successfully from your Google Account. Check your below details.</p>
  {% if google_data is not none %}
    <div class="detail">
      <p style="font-size: 15px; padding-bottom: 10px;">User info fetched from <strong>{{ fetch_url }}</strong></p>
      <table border='1'>
      {% for key, value in google_data.items() %}
        <tr><td>{{ key }}</td> <td><strong>{{ value }}</strong></td></tr>
      {% endfor %}
      </table>
    </div>
    <div> <img src="{{ google_data.picture }}" alt="User Picture">    </div>
  {% endif %}
  {% endif %}

</html>

I created it locally and tried it on Google Cloud Shell.  I expected it authenticate to google and show my info.  Instead i get the "Access blocked: This app’s request is invalid" page

I'm unfamiliar with Flask-Dance but it appears that the auth service is unable to redirect back to your Cloud Shell app upon approval. The last line in your comments above your code includes redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%3A5000%2Flogin%2Fgoogle%2Fauthorized which decodes to redirect_uri=http://127.0.0.1:5000/login/google/authorized which is probably not the URL for the Cloud Shell instance. I'm unsure how deterministic Cloud Shell DNS names are but you should likely anticipate this value changing too.

That isnt even remotely how authorization works for web applications you should have a look at the documentation web-server#python

Thanks replying DazWilkin and @Linda Lawton - DaImTo  I copied the example at link and I got it working fine locally but the same problem when I deploy to Google Cloud Shell. "Access blocked: This app’s request is invalid"
I would love to have a working example of oauth in python that works on Google Shell (GCP). I am going to try DazWilkin thoughts on the redirect_uri
